# Get the nth date of a month in a year

Tags: python, pandas

How can i get the 15 of every month in a year?

I tried with:

```
dates=pd.date_range(start='15/1/2001',end='15/12/2001', freq='M')
```

But is not getting the 15th of every month.

How can i do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you specifically need a pandas solution? If not then a very simple `for` loop will do.

Comment: Month Start + offset -> `pd.date_range(start='15/12/2000', end='15/12/2001', freq='MS') + pd.DateOffset(days=14)`